# I am trying to use swiper js but it just wont work, I don't know what I am doing wrong here .. please tell what is wrong here

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

this is the entire code , please see what is the problem here, i have done everything given on the swiper js website. i have added the style links in the header and the required scripts in the body

```html
<body>
    <!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <!-- Slides -->
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      ...
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  
    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  
    <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
      const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  // Optional parameters
  direction: 'vertical',
  loop: true,

  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },

  // And if we need scrollbar
  scrollbar: {
    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
  },
});

  </script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to put your code below the other scripts. You're trying to use `Swiper` before it is defined.

Comment: @AndreNuechter thank you so much you are right, its working now